# ¿Cómo puedo asignar valores a un struct que está en otro archivo.c?

Tags: c

Tengo un archivo. c, donde está este struct:

```
typedef struct coordenada{
   int col;
   int fila;
}coordenada_t
```

y en otro .c quiero asignar valores a fila y col, y la forma en la que lo estoy haciendo es la siguiente:

```
fila = 5;
col = 7;
coordenada_t.fila = fila;
coordenada_t.col = col;
```

¿Pueden decirme la forma en la que puedo asignar valores?, ya que al compilarlo me da este error:

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token coordenada_t.fila = fila;
                                                               ^
error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token coordenada_t.col = col;
                                                               ^
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar en la pregunta cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: Tienes que crear un `coordenada_t`, y a ese le puedes asignar los valores. `coordenada_t coordenada; coordenada.fila = fila; coordenada.col = col;`

Answer (score 0):

> Tengo un archivo. c, donde está este struct:

Esta afirmación no es correcta. No tienes un `struct`. Ahí simplemente has declarado un tipo nuevo de dato, llamado `coordenada_t`, que tiene dos campos de tipo `int`. Pero ahí no has declarado ninguna variable, solo has declarado un tipo de dato.

> y en otro .c quiero asignar valores a fila y col,

Vale, entonces tienes que hacer algunos cambios.

Para empezar, deberías mover la declaración a un archivo de cabecera (.h). Esta acción permitirá que ambos archivos conozcan tu estructura y puedan trabajar con ella:

###### coordenada.h

```
#ifndef COORDENADA_T
#define COORDENADA_T

typedef struct coordenada{
   int col;
   int fila;
} coordenada_t;

#endif
```

Ahora ya puedes declarar y usar variables de este tipo allí donde hagas un include a este archivo

```
#include "coordenada.h"

void func()
{
    coordenada_t coordenada;
    // ...
}
```

Centrándonos en tu problema, dices que te gustaría modificar una variable que se encuentra en otro archivo. El mecanismo más común para hacer esto es usar funciones:

###### eldato.h

```
#ifndef ELDATO_H
#define ELDATO_H

#include "coordenada.h"

coordenada_t GetCoordenada();

void SetCoordenada(coordenada_t coordenada);

void ImprimirCoordenada();

#endif
```

###### eldato.cpp

```
#include "eldato.h"

coordenada_t coordenadaOculta = { .fila = 1, .col = 2 };

coordenada_t GetCoordenada()
{ return coordendaOculta; }

void SetCoordenada(coordenada_t coordenada)
{ coordenadaOculta = coordenada; }

void ImprimirCoordenada()
{ printf("%d %d\n", coordenadaOculta .fila, coordenadaOculta .col); }
```

###### main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "eldato.h"

int main()
{
    ImprimirCoordenada();

    coordenada_t coordenada;
    coordenada.fila = 20;
    coordenada.columna = 30;

    SetCoordenada(coordenada);
    ImprimirCoordenada();
}
```

También podrías conseguir el mismo efecto con `extern`, pero es un uso que no te aconsejaría, al menos no mientras aprendes:

```
int main()
{
    extern coordenada_t coordenadaOculta;
    
    ImprimirCoordenada();

    coordenadaOculta.fila = 20;
    coordenadaOculta.col = 30;

    ImprimirCoordenada();
}
```

Lo que hace `extern` es buscar una variable que tenga el mismo nombre que la que estás declarando y pasa a usar dicha variable.